# Validating alphanumeric in a shell script gone wrong

Tags: bash, shell, validation

So I've been following a shell script (bash) from a book, and it supposedly validates some alphanumeric input

**Code:**

```
#! /bin/bash
# This script validates given alphanumeric
    validAlphNum(){
    # Returns 0 if it is, 1 if not
    
    # Remove unwanted chars
    validchars= "$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/[^[:alnum:]]//g')"
    
    if [ "$validchars" = "$1" ] ; then
        return 0
    else 
        return 1
    fi
}

/bin/echo -n "Enter input : "
read input

#input validation
if ! validAlphNum "$input" ; then
    echo "Please enter ONLY Letters and Numbers" >&2
    exit 1
else
    echo "Input is valid"
fi
exit 0
```

when i try to run it ( `roman-coder@romancoder:~$ valid_alnum` )
I get this output

```
Enter input : echo

Please enter ONLY Letters and Numbers
```

which is not working like it should because "echo" is a valid string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
validchars= "$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/[^[:alnum:]]//g')"
```

to

```
validchars="$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/[^[:alnum:]]//g')"
```

that extra space after `=` is tripping your script

Comment: Worked, thank you so much, but honestly it is quite confusing working with spaces, is there a specific pattern to it ?

Comment: as per the docs, when assigning a variable: `no spaces on either side of =` are allowed